# use if else statement to add class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```html
<!-- draggable -->
<div class="draggable">
  <img src="img/draggable.png" alt="draggable" />
  <div class="drag-area">
    <div class="year year1"></div>
    <div class="year year2"></div>
    <div class="year year3"></div>
    <div class="year year4"></div>
    <div class="year year5"></div>
    <div class="year year58"></div>
    <div class="btn btn-draggable-ball">
      <img src="img/draggable-ball.png" alt="draggable-ball" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- popup -->
<div class="btn btn-popup" id="btn-popup"></div>
<div class="popup-1" id="popup" style="z-index: 50">
  <div class="answer-1"></div>
  <div class="answer-2"></div>
  <div id="close" class="btn"></div>
</div>
<div class="popup-2" id="popup" style="z-index: 50">
  <div class="answer-2-2"></div>
  <div id="close" class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
$(".btn-draggable-ball").on("touchend", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // $(".year2").addClass("drop");
  // $(".year58").addClass("drop");

  if ($(".year").hasClass("year2")) {
    $(".year2").addClass("drop");
  } else if ($(".year").hasClass("year58")) {
    $(".year58").addClass("drop");
  }
});

$(".btn-popup").on("click", () => {
  if ($(".year2").hasClass("drop")) {
    $(".popup-1").show();
  } else if ($(".year58").hasClass("drop")) {
    $(".popup-2").show();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

$(".popup-1 #close").on("click", () => {
  $(".popup-1").hide();
});

$(".popup-2 #close").on("click", () => {
  $(".popup-2").hide();
});
```

Now I use draggable to do  if else statement  to judgement and add the class, after adding class it can show different when I click the button.

And I have some problem,

1. If else statement on touchend didn’t work.
2. Even I draggable the ball to another div it also do the if condition and it can’t do the else if condition.

Comment: your class `.btn-draggable-ball` does not exist in your DOM

Comment: @Apodemus you mean this one?  `<div class="btn btn-draggable-ball">`

Answer (score 0):

The `else if` does not work because your first `if` condition is already true. It will always be true, since your `.year` always has the class `.year2`. This is why only `.year2` gets updated.

You do already add a class to your `.year2`, I tested it that part and it actually works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your response, if I want to let the two condition toggle, how can I do?

Comment: You might be looking for the `toggleClass` method. [link](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: But as you said, if condition is already true, else if condition is still not working, and it didn't toggle by .year 2 and .year 58

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal of your script is, but as long as `.year` has the class`.year2`, `.year58` will never get `.drop`

Comment: You'll either need to change your if-condition or remove the `.year2` class once the condition has been met.